# Impact of moving Magento 2 website from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 5.6

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I have developed a Magento 2.1.x website on my local server, which has **`MySQL version 5.7`**.

Now, the server where I need to deploy the website has **`CentOS 6`**, which supports **`MySQL version 5.6`**.

My question is whether there will be any issues if I migrate my **Magento 2** website from a server having **`MySQL 5.7`** to another server which has **`MySQL version 5.6`**?

**Note:** I have checked the **official documents of Magento 2.1.x** and found that **`Magento 2.1.x is compatible with MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7`** both.

Comment: upgrade to mysql 5.7

Comment: Server is not in my hands and cent os 6 can support upto MySQL 5.6

Comment: then again you can test it on your local system if it works or not